# best way to communicate to end user about flurry

Tags: android, iphone, ios, flurry

Apologize in advance if this question is not appropriate for this forum, but I am trying to figure out whats the best way to tell the user that my app is using Flurry. Is there a requirement to tell the user his device is sending data to flurry? Who do most apps "tell" the user that this app is sending data to the flurry servers? is it part of the end user license agreement? whats the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

What should you do, and what most app *do* are probably pretty different.

I'd imagine that most apps have some form of analytics, and few bother to tell their users.

More progressive apps (from a social perspective) are informing their users via a EULA. I cannot speak for Android, but in the iOS App Store Apple makes it very easy to add a EULA to your app when you submit it.

In fact, being honest up front is probably best in light of recent and upcoming laws: http://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=d2bfdafd-5164-439d-8b38-48bd13d71a71